# Single large graph partitioninig in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a single large graph. I assumed that the graph doesn't fit in the main memory. I want to partition the graph and distribute on the nodes on the cluster. then I want mining frequent subgraph in this graph. Based the nature of frequent subgraph mining problem and the relation between graph, I need a method that divides the graph into the N section so that  I can determine each vertex of graph placed in the given node. I want to use hadoop, mapreduce to write my algorithm, but I don't know how do that ?

Comment: HDFS method meaning what? Have you using an actual Graph database? HDFS doesn't have any concept of partitions

Comment: I know that When loading a file in HDFS, the file based on the block size partitioned and placed in different nodes, but I want to be able to determine which part of the graph will be located in each node.

Comment: You cannot pick which blocks are placed on datanodes in HDFS. And you need a namenode, not just a datanode if you want to follow HDFS

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "partitioned", or why you've convinced yourself that Hadoop or MapReduce is a solution to your problem. Apache Spark has a GraphX is a *processing library*, but not storage. Apache Giraph is another one on top of Hadoop. Apache Titan is no longer developed, and is part of the DataStax Cassandra Graph Database offering... Or you can use Neo4j or OrientDB or JanusGraph... None of these require you to use HDFS

Comment: I have a single large graph. I assumed that the graph doesn't fit in the main memory. I want to partition the graph and distribute on the nodes on the cluster. then I want mining frequent subgraph in this graph. Based the nature of frequent subgraph mining problem and the relation between graph, I need a method that divides the graph into the N section so that  I can determine each vertex of graph placed in the given node.

Comment: Again, what alternatives have you considered that don't require Hadoop, since that isn't going to give you what you need out of the box.